# InvalidAuthenticityToken in Users::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, csrf, unicorn

I have in production my app, and when I try to login this error appears. The code is this:

View:

```
    = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      .col-xs-12
        = devise_error_messages!
      .col-xs-12.field
        = f.label :email
        = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class:"form-control"
      .col-xs-12.field
        = f.label :password
        = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class:"form-control"
      - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
        .col-xs-12.field.remember-me
          .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.remember
            = f.check_box :remember_me
            = f.label :remember_me
          .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.forgot-password
            = link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name)
      .col-xs-12.actions.text-center
        = f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-default principal-btn"

      .col-xs-12.links.text-center
        = link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name)
```

Sessions Controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #  super
  # end
end
```

In Application Controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
```

Versions:

```
devise (4.2.0)
rails (5.0.0.1)
unicorn (5.1.0)
unicorn-rails (2.2.1)
ruby (2.3.1)
```

My server is an aws instance, and the application is launched with unicorn.

I have tried:

```
# Users::SessionsController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]
```

and

```
# ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery with: :null_sessions
```

but this is so unsure and sessions are not created. So, I don't know another way to solve this issue.

Comment: You have this issue in only `production` or you also have it in `development` as well ?

Comment: Only production

Comment: make sure you have turn cookies on in production :)